# CsProj migration: dynamic becoming object on Microsoft.Excel.Interop assembly

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, visual-studio-2017, csproj

[C# 4.6 on VS 2017]

We are currently migrating our Csproj from the old format to the new format (obviously), and we are facing a weird issue.

One project is using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly. At some point we manipulate Excel Range attributes like this:

```
public static void ApplyGradient(Range rng)
{
    rng.FormatConditions[1].ColorScaleCriteria[1].FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0;
}
```

When browsing to the assembly from VS, we observe different Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel signatures in **old** and **new** projects. Here is what we see:

- [Microsoft...Excel seen in **old** solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUjAd.png) => attributes are `dynamic`
- [Microsoft...Excel seen in **new** solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zofB3.png) => attributes are `object`

The result is a compilation issue, in the new version of csproj, because `ColorScaleCriteria` is not understood as a property of `object` obviously.

We have tried several actions, like adding the `System.Dynamic.Runtime` dependency in our project, but it did not solve anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably after two+ years this is not relevant anymore, but for people that are facing the same problem:

You need to remove the NuGet reference to `Bundle.Microsoft.Office.Interop` / `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

Add the COM Reference to `Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library` and set `Copy Local`and `Embed Interop Types` to `Yes`.

Or you can just add this to your .csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Excel.dll">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>9</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>00020813-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
      <Private>true</Private>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Got the solution from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59138607