# .NET core 3.0 and MS Office Interop not working together in some scenarios

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, wpf-core

I am using `WPF .NET Core 3.1` app to automate `Microsoft WORD`. As we know `Office COM` references don't work with .NET Core 3.1. But there is a workaround as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58130770/1232087) or as explained in the `Note` section here in an [official .NET Core Excel sample](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/ExcelDemo) or another workaround explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59138607/1232087).

The above mentioned workarounds work in almost all cases in my `WPF Core 3.1` app for `WORD` automation except in some cases such as the one shown below where I get the following error at the last line of the code:

**Code**:

```
....
using WORD = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
oApp = new WORD.Application();
oApp.Visible = true;
WORD.Document oDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\tmp\Test.docx");

string st = oDoc.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text; //this line correctly shows the content of Paragraph[1]
st = oDoc.Paragraphs[1].get_Style().NameLocal; //this line throws the error shown below
```

**Error**:

> > System._ComObject does not contain a definition for NameLocal

**Remark**: The above error does not occur in my similar project in WPF `.NET FullNetwork` app. And there it correctly displays the value of `oDoc.Paragraphs[1].get_Style().NameLocal` as `Normal` if the paragraph is a normal paragraph, or it displays, say, `Heading 1` if paragraph is a Heading 1 etc.

**Question**: What could be the cause of the error in the above `WPF .NET Core 3.1` app and how can we remedy it?

Comment: Fixed in [.NETCore v5](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12587).  Workaround is to cast the return value of get_Style() to Style yourself.