# Cannot open Excel file using C#

Tags: c#

I try to open a excel file using c# but it doesn't work for me, I receive FileNotFoundException error.

**Error**

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The specified file can not be found.

ExcelWebApp.Controllers.ValuesController.Get()

    Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing 

    FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
        ExcelWebApp.Controllers.ValuesController.Get()
        lambda_method(Closure , object , object[] )
        Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(object target, object[] parameters)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: I use Windows server 2019 standard 64 bits, Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5.5

Comment: Please provide the code you used too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine needs to have the corresponding version of Office installed.

Comment: I use MO Pro Plus 2016 (only word & excel).

Comment: I see you are using AspNetCore, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130446/net-core-3-0-and-ms-office-interop

Comment: Thanks Marc, I've changed the technology from Core to .Net Framework and it works.