# interop exception when trying to read the contents of an office outlook template

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, email-templates, oft

I am trying to read an office template (.oft file) with embedded images in the body of the email. I tried using [the MsgReader nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MsgReader/) which reads the contents, but cant manage the images in the body.

I have also tried using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, but this throws the following error at runtime :

Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

I am struggling to find a solution to this. On my work computer i have Office 365 installed. in the about tab is says Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.12827.20200) 32-bit

So far based on what i have read, i have tried running my prototype project in IIS instead of IIS Express, but this did not resolve the problem. Do I need to install a specific version of Outlook, or some redistribution files? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get he interop to work, but found a working third party solution : https://downloads.aspose.com/email/net

[this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Email/) nuget package will read the body content including images corretly without the need for using interop.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

It seems you just need a reference to the `office.dll` assembly as well. For example, search for the `Microsoft Office library` in the COM references section:

[image: Add a COM reference dialog window]

Also, I've noticed that you are running the solution under IIS.

> So far based on what i have read, i have tried running my prototype project in IIS instead of IIS Express, but this did not resolve the problem.

Here is what Microsoft states for that:

> All current versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They assume an interactive desktop and user profile. They do not provide the level of reentrancy or security that is necessary to meet the needs of server-side components that are designed to run unattended.

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

Your choices are listed below:

- Use a low-level API that can be run under a service - Extended MAPI or EWS, see [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.
- Use third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Note, the [[MS-OXMSG]: Outlook Item (.msg) File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82) is described in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this but it didnt work for me. I found a library that does read the images into the body though https://downloads.aspose.com/email/net

Comment: That is what exactly I meant when describing `Use third-party components designed for the server-side execution.`

Answer (score 0):

When using interop types with .NET Core, **use a COM reference** to the particular Office Object Library **instead of the NuGet package**:

[image]

[image]

And set **Embed Interop Types** and **Copy Local** to **Yes**:

[image: 3]

See [.NET core 3.0 and MS Office Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130446/net-core-3-0-and-ms-office-interop) for more details.