# How to save .xls file using OpenXML in dot net core?

Tags: excel, .net-core, xls, openxml-sdk

I want to create a **.xls** file using OpenXML SDK. I am able to create .xlsx and .xlsm files but when i save it as .xls and open in my system it pops an **error**. Then I have to do save as again for it to work properly.
Is there any way to **save files directly in .xls format**?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is `No`, you cannot do it.

The reason being .xls format is proprietary to Microsoft. OpenXml SDK cannot understand or write to that format.
If you want to store data in .xls format, then you need to use Microsoft office excel interop objects.

[Excel namespace interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia)

If you indeed want to take the route of adding interops to your application to save to .xls format, I would also suggest you to look into following SO answer because adding reference to interop objects in .NET core is not straight forward.

[ms interop in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130446/net-core-3-0-and-ms-office-interop)