# How to solve Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel .net Standard "Could not load file or assembly" Exception?

Tags: excel, .net-core, office-interop, .net-standard

I've checked many posts and references about this but still cannot solve it.

I have a .Net Standard project that references Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
Everything is fine up until the runtime where I want to initiate an excel (read and/or write) and I get this exception:

```
'Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified
```

It works fine on .NET Framework 4.6.1 but it does not on .net core and standard.

Her is my GAC
[image]

What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that it was because I use .NET Core.
I should use COM reference too.

The answer that helped me is here
[.NET core 3.0 and MS Office Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130446/net-core-3-0-and-ms-office-interop)