# Pipeline on Azure Devops is failing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-5

a month ago we had a solution (big one) in .net framework 4.7.2. This was building fine on azure devops pipeline.

Now we ported our solution to net5.
Everything is working in visual studio but on azure devops, the pipeline is failing.

We had to change our Microsoft.Interop.Word (and excel, and outlook) to a com reference. Because net5 is multiplatform and interop is not.

Because we removed the nuget packages and changed to com reference the pipeline is failing.
Does anyone know how to handle this specific problem?
We can't remove the interop.excel and etc from our projects because they are dependent on it.

Beneath you see the result we have.
[image]

It feels like we have tried everything to make it work again on azure devops.

[image]

Comment: Does your pipeline run on windows, or on ubuntu?

Comment: I've added the yaml of the pipeline. The pipeline is on Azure Devops of microsoft on their servers.

Comment: The vmImage is windows-latest, so it's running on Windows.

Comment: Hi did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue

Comment: We made it work with a nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

have you consider [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) since you have requirement to stay the external library in this case `Microsoft.Office.Interops` and I don't think Microsoft Azure DevOps Pipeline agent support that currently.

With self-hosted agent, you install the [PIAs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) and link your library/com references to the paths.

Comment: Ok that would be a possible solutions. But it is a big change to the current system. I would like to hope there is another solution for this issue.

Answer (score -1):

There is problem with assembly in the code, your code may be building on local environment as it is getting references for all assemblies however when you checking in the code pipelines could not fetch the assemblies through nuget package restore, if you are referencing assembly from local machine, make sure you add its nuget package reference package.config file, so nuget restore will restore the package

can you try below
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039601/microsoft-interop-excel-with-net5-0-is-not-working)

Comment: Well i didn't reference a dll from my local machine. Normally we always add a nuget package. But for interop.excel of word they don't exist for NET5. We added a com reference instead.