# Unable to cast COM object of type Interop.Word(TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)

Tags: c#

This is my system environment

- Windows 10 64bit
- Office 2013 32bit
- Visual Studio 2019, Build Only x86
- I have no choice but to use 32bit excel.
- I develop with C# and I already reference assembly
- I also checked reference properties : Local copy(true), Include interop type(true)
- Object Framework is .NET 5.0
- Output : Console application

The error comes up this below code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

And Error message like below.

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)

What is important :

- **I already tried restore, uninstall MicroSoft Office 3 times.**

Also I search it on Google almost 7 days
I tried like this site [Error accessing COM components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957595/error-accessing-com-components)

But Always faild to solve the error.

Now I'm gonna crazy. Please give me any help

Comment: The first link leads to: [Unable to cast COM object of Office Interop Word](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d34c4f78-46f3-478e-9c44-95ea8461e46f/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-office-interop-word?forum=vsto)

Comment: @Luuk I tried it but it didn't work for me...

Comment: I cannot get it to work in .NET5 (but getting different errors).  I get this Warning: "Warning NU1701 Package 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 15.0.4797.1003' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'."

Comment: Then you mean, in the net5.0 "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" doesn't work. right?

Comment: With my limited knowledge of C# I did draw that conclusion.  I am trying to find (online) resources that confirm that, but was unsuccessfull (see: [github.com/dotnet/runtime...](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43426), [developercommunity.visualstudio.com/...](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/make-net-5-app-support-officeinterop/1332337), [Microsoft Interop Excel with .Net5.0 is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039601/microsoft-interop-excel-with-net5-0-is-not-working) )

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is : I run my program on the visual studio with **administrator mode**.

It seems that when I run with administrator(after I will say this as 'admin'), some privileges issue pops up internally. Therefore it seems to my computer could not load the library/dll.

Although I can't say exact mechanism even more detail because I'm not major in computer science, surely the problem is solved when I run with 'not' admin mode. And it doesn't get any error since I changed it.